# What distribution is appropriate for modeling internet forum posting?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, model

Internet message boards, such as 4chan, consist of a series of "threads" to which people post replies. One observes that most threads receive zero or one reply, a few receive 2 or more, and only the most exceptional reach 50 or 100. Theoretically speaking, what should the distribution of the response count to a randomly selected thread be? Initially, I was thinking of something like a Poisson distribution, but there are various weird effects to account for. The underlying problem is that replies to threads are not independent events. For example, once a thread has a critical mass of replies, it is more likely to snowball into a large debate, further inflating the post count.

I suspect this corresponds (at least approximately) to some well-known statistical model, but I'm not sure which.

For concreteness, [here's a sample of post counts](http://pastebin.com/ZMaRvZuV) from 3000 consecutive threads, taken from a major, prestigious message board. The format is [reply count, number of threads with that reply count]. (Actually, the count includes the initial post, so subtract one to get the number of replies.)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a [zeta distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_distribution) could make a reasonable first approximation to the number of posts (rather than the number of replies). [See also [Zipf's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%27s_law)]

[image]

But one should not read too much into seeing data that [resembles a power law](http://bactra.org/weblog/491.html)[1]

[1]: Shalizi, C. (2007),
 "So You Think You Have a Power Law — Well Isn't That Special?"
 *Three Toed Sloth* blog, June 15.  [link](http://bactra.org/weblog/491.html)